# What universe did She-Hulk enter?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, she-hulk-attorney-at-law

The MCU is set in Universe '*Earth-199999*'. As *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* is set in the MCU, it is also part of this universe.

As you can see below, She-Hulk enters the Disney+ home screen. This made little sense to me, as she has now surely entered a new universe. What universe is she now in, and does this mean she has the capability to move to other universes whenever she pleases (somewhat like America Chavez's power in *Doctor Strange: In the Multiverse of Madness*)?

[image: She-Hulk Entering Disney +]

Comment: I have gotten the distinct idea that She-Hulk should not be taken serious, and that this is a great example of it completely missing the concept of meta-comedy (and keeping it consistent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She-Hulk was able to enter the MCU’s version of the real world in the Season 1 finale ("Whose Show Is This?"), in keeping with the self-referential and fourth-wall-breaking nature of the show and her characterization.

And yes, She-Hulk can travel to a different universe — the “real world” — and interact with the creators of her own show, convincing them to change certain plot elements in the episode and its ending, altering the reality of the Marvel Cinematic Universe. Her ability to do so is based on the comics, where she was able to do the same.

> Gao cites the John Byrne run of SHE-HULK comics for inspiration for this *extreme* four-wall break, explaining “It felt natural that not only that she was in a show, but that she would have opinions about the show, especially since she just was completely betrayed by the makers of this show. It just felt right that she would go and complain to the ultimate lord of Marvel, which is K.E.V.I.N..”

<sup>- [*‘She-Hulk’: Introducing Marvel Studios’ K.E.V.I.N.* Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/she-hulk-finale-kevin)</sup>

However, K.E.V.I.N. has said that She-Hulk would not be able to go to the "real world" in the MCU again.

> **K.E.V.I.N.:**  You will not be able to access the K-E-V-I-N again.
> […]
> That error on our platform has been fixed.

[*Sensational She-Hulk* #50](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sensational_She-Hulk_Vol_1_50) (1993) by John Byrne was the inspiration for the show's plotline, in which She-Hulk interacted with the editors and writers of her own comic book (including John Byrne) and got to choose how her story would unfold.

[image: screencaps of Sensational She-Hulk #50][image][image]

Comment: Accepted on the grounds of conformation that she did, in fact, enter a new universe, but it would be pretty neat to know which one!

Comment: @taylor.2317 Do you mean an identifier like Earth-616 or Earth-838? As far as I know, the "real world" in the MCU hasn't been assigned an identifier like that. I'll update my answer if it has.

Comment: Yup, that was the question, yet it is highly likely that we haven't been told (yet?) Thanks